# Does pm2 auto restart application after reboot by default?

Tags: node.js, linux, pm2

I have an issue with my linux server and need to reboot, before that I run my node application with `pm2 start server.js` without any other config. Can it auto restart my app after reboot server?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Not by default, but PM2 can do so using a [startup script](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/startup/):

> PM2 can generate startup scripts and configure them in order to keep
>   your process list intact across expected or unexpected machine
>   restarts.

After generating your startup script (read also this [comment](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/startup/#comment-4743098045)), take a look at `pm2 save`:

> Once you started all the applications you want to manage, you have to
>   save the list you wanna respawn at machine reboot with:
>
> `pm2 save`

Comment: so in short: run `pm2 startup` and when all the right processes are running that you want to automatically restart at reboot save them with `pm2 save`

Comment: @Ravindra See [`pm2-installer`](https://github.com/jessety/pm2-installer): _`pm2-installer` is designed to automate installation of pm2 as a service, particularly on Windows, even in environments without Internet access._

Comment: @Flion "pm2 startup" only prints a bash command that you need to copy and execute manually. After that, the processes you saved will be restarted on boot.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this script before run `pm2 save`:

```
pm2 startup
[PM2] You have to run this command as root. Execute the following command:
      sudo su -c "env PATH=$PATH:/home/unitech/.nvm/versions/node/v14.3/bin pm2 startup <distribution> -u <user> --hp <home-path>
```

https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/startup/

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can.
Suppose your pm2 is running having some processes.
First, you need to save the processes.

```
pm2 save
```

Next, you need to run the pm2 in startup. So if system rebooted your pm2  automatically started with processes.

```
pm2 startup
```

Thats it!
https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/startup/

Answer (score 0):

No, if you do not add a startup command then it will close after reboot so

you can use:

```bash
pm2 startup ubuntu
```

After this, it's always run after closing the server in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I used another alternative way on Ubuntu 20.04 and it worked!

Make sure you have saved the pm2 configuration (**pm2 save**)

**First edit the crontab file**

```
crontab -e
```

**Then paste the following command**

```
@reboot /usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 resurrect && /usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 start all
```

Answer (score -2):

**First of all I run below command**

`pm2 save`

**Then Run**

```
 pm2 resurrect
```

Comment: `pm2 save`, then `pm2 resurrect` on each (windows) start

Comment: This will try to resurrect PM2 every minute, which doesn't seem like a perfect Idea.